# Template doubt in C++

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T> void test()
{
     cout << "Called from template T";
}
template<int I> void test()
{
     cout << "Called from int";
}
int main()
{
     test<int()>();      
}
```

In the above snippet `test<int()>()` calls the first version and gives output

`Called from template T`

Why doesn't the second version get called?

Comment: In your example int() is interpreted as an int (void) type (ie a function). Compare with std::tr1::function<int()>.

Answer (score 11):

As per ISO C++03 (`Section 14.3/2`)

In  a template-argument, an ambiguity between a `type-id` and an expression is resolved to a `type-id`.  `int()` is a `type-id` so the first version gets called.

Comment: Technically correct, though you could mention that using test<2>() will call the second one, since `2` resolves to `int`.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
test<(int())>();
```

Comment: @sbi no it's a good hint, although misses some explanation. The parens around `int()` make it an expression of type `int`.

Comment: @Johannes: Indeed. _I_ should have tried before I blurted out... @tyms: Sorry. I removed my down-vote. (But I won't up-vote because this doesn't explain why yours would work.)

Answer (score 5):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to achieve with this.
But if you wanted to use a different template specialization when you instantiate the template with an int rather than any other type then this is the syntax you need -

```
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std;

  template<typename T> void test()
  {
       cout << "Called from template T";
  }

  template<> void test<int>()
  {
       cout << "Called from int";
  }


  int main()
  {
          test<int>(); 

  }
```

Comment: `+1` for the only answer here that shows how to do what, IMO, Rahul actually wanted to do - define a specialization.

Comment: A bit OT: In general I would say that method specialization is discouraged. Herb Sutter tells the story better than me: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: @FuleSnabel: I avoid using overloading instead of the missing function template _partial_ specialization, but I've  always used _full_ specialization.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted the second template to be invoked whenever `T` is `int`. [John has shown you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792625/template-doubt-in-c/3793166#3793166) how to do that, and [Benoit has shown you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792625/template-doubt-in-c/3792649#3792649) what you need to do in order to actually call the second function.

Your problem is that by trying to *specialize* `test<>()` for a specific type (`int`) using the completely wrong syntax, ***you have accidentally hit another valid syntactic form***. (Kind of bad luck.) That second function template is using a so-called *non-type template parameter*. For besides types you can use other things as template parameters. Among others (functions, templates) you can also use integral constants, like `int`. Had you tried to do this with, say, `double`, the code would have failed to compile.
Your second `test<>()` template is an *overload* of the first one which can be used with constant integers. That's why Benoit's `test<0>()` would compile.

For a full specialization (there is no *partial* specialization for function templates, there's just overloading; class templates, however, do have partial specialization), you have to always provide an empty template parameter list (`template<>`) and put the types to specialize for behind the identifier `test<int>`.

Comment: While I have been doing a lot of things wrong on this whole thread, unless you point out to what's wrong with my answer, it's not fair to down-vote it.